# Can I avoid anything with Akuma's Ashura Senku (teleport)?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

For instance, is it possible to pass through any other character's super or ultra ?  Or through Zangief's Banishing Flat (green hand), or a Shoryuken ?

[image: Akuma's Ashura Senku (teleport) in action]

In this case, doesn't it make Akuma virtually invincible to any attacks ?

Also I have the feeling that the Ashura Senku performed at the beginning of Raging Demon doesn't work the same way.  Once I've been stopped in this move by a simple light punch (quite well timed I suppose).  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akuma's teleport is invincible (as well as unthrowable) beginning on the first frame, but it has a small recovery period at the end where he is vulnerable. As such, it's mainly used to safely escape pressure, but you're vulnerable if your opponent predicts your teleport, or if they use an [option select](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHHoGHcgK9k) designed to counter a teleport attempt.

The "teleport" animation that happens as a part of the Raging Demon is largely vulnerable (aside from some startup invincibility on the Ultra version), and if you're hit, it will be canceled. It's generally recommended to Demon only when you *know* (or can predict) that the opponent will be committed to another action so that they can't avoid or cancel it.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.  I had no idea about options selects, gotta read about that.